# Probability median of three is the second smallest

Tags: probability, median

Consider three integers  $x_1, x_2, x_3$ sampled from the integers $\{1,\dots,n\}$ uniformly at random (with replacement). I would like to know the probability that the median of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ equals $2$.

The probability that any of them equals $2$ is $1-(1-\frac{1}{n})^3$.

Comment: Well, I suppose the natural starting point is to count the triples with median $2$.  we've got $(1,2, *)$ and $(2,2,,*)$ where $*≥2$., for example.  Note:  it is not clear from your post whether you are sampling with or without replacement.

Comment: @lulu With replacement. It's in the brackets.

Comment: Ah, so it is.  So then my two patterns are both valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible mutually exclusive cases:

1. All three integers are equal to $2$. Probability of this case is $\frac{1}{n^3}$
2. Two integers are equal to 2 and the other one is not. Probability of this case is $\frac{3(n-1)}{n^3}$
3. One integer is less than 2 (that is equal to 1), one is greater than 2 (that is neither 2 nor 1), one is equal to 2. Probability of this case is $\frac{6(n-2)}{n^3}$

The total probability is $\frac{1}{n^3} + \frac{3(n-1)}{n^3} + \frac{6(n-2)}{n^3} = \frac{9n - 14}{n^3}$

Comment: Thank you very much!